# Software, in active development, for planetary or solar system generation

Tags: offline, 3d, astronomy

[Mojoworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MojoWorld_Generator) was a procedural planet generation software. However, development ceased over a decade ago, and the creator not only actively avoids answering any questions about possible future development (based on personal email exchanges with him), the sites for the software have gone defunct.

Is there any other software which duplicates the functionality of planetary scale generation? Solar system and galactic scales are also acceptable, so long as close-in planetary scale is available.

The question [Star System and/or Galaxy modelling/procedural generation software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/star-system-and-or-galaxy-modelling-procedural-generation-software) is close, but I need the ability to zoom in on the planet to the human-level view, in addition to any solar system or galactic level generation capabilities, so it does not quite fit. I am also in need of the ability to perform local edits post-generation.

OS: I can get any of them that I need. (OS X would take me the longest at current, so Windows, *nix, Android, or iOS would be fastest.)